# How to know if a makefile variable is a string of char or numbers?

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, gnu-make

It probably sounds very elementary but I am unable to find a way to classify a makefile variable into text or number. My pseudocode is like this:

```
ifeq ($N, 'numeric')
CFLAGS+=-D$N
endif
```

How to do this? I am using the GNU Make (in cygwin/Windows). I read the make.pdf that comes with it but could not find a way.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To bring another option on the table: [gmtt has a function to dissect strings into character classes](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/master/README.md#call-chop-strstringgroup-stringgroup-stringgroup-stringgroup-string).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: adopted a suggestion by *bobbogo* that does not depend on the number of characters to *purge*.

I assume you use GNU make. Here is a make-only solution, without calling the shell. For performance reasons, depending on your use of it, it can be preferable. Moreover, it does not depend on which shell make uses. Last but not least, it uses recursion and I like recursion:

```
define PURGE
$(if $(2),$(call PURGE,$(subst $(firstword $(2)),,$(1)),$(filter-out $(firstword $(2)),$(2))),$(1))
endef

DIGITS := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
define IS_NOT_A_NUMBER
$(call PURGE,$(1),$(DIGITS))
endef

CFLAGS += $(if $(call IS_NOT_A_NUMBER,$(N)),,-D$(N))
all:
    $(info N=$(N) => CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS))
```

Demo:

```
host> make N=12345
N=12345 => CFLAGS=-D12345
make: 'all' is up to date.

host> make N=foobar
N=foobar => CFLAGS=
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

Explanation: `PURGE` is a recursive macro that takes two arguments. The first one (`$(1)`) is a string to test, the second one (`$(2)`) is a list of words to match. If `$(2)` is the empty list `PURGE` returns `$(1)`. Else, it calls itself with two new parameters:

- the value of `$(1)` where the first word of `$(2)` has been substituted by nothing,
- `$(2)` from which the first word has been removed

and returns the result. So, if you call `PURGE` with a string and the list of all digits, it returns the empty string if and only if the string contained only digits.

Comment: `$(wordlist 2,10,$2)` is silently limiting you to 10 chars. `$(filter-out $(firstword $2),$2)` maybe?

Comment: @bobbogo: Nice suggestion. I edited my answer to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All make variables are strings.  To find out whether a string is in fact a number, you need some elementary text analysis functions.  GNU make itself does not offer anything convenient in this area, but you could run a shell command to do the job, perhaps like this:

```
define is_number
$(shell test '$(1)' -eq '$(1)' 2>/dev/null && echo yes || echo no)
endef

ifeq ($(call is_number, $(N)),yes)
default:
    @echo N is a number
else
default:
    @echo N is not a number
endif
```

This results in:

```
$ make N=5
N is a number
$ make N=string
N is not a number
```

However, such string processing can be quite unreliable if the string contains special characters.